Use a combinatorial proof to show that $1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = {n+1 \choose 2} + 2{n+1 \choose 3}$
For this question, I tried to list out n+1 objects and count the number of ways by conditioning on whether certain objects were selected or not but that didn't get me anywhere, then I tried to use the method I was taught in class where you are essentially "forming a committee" and tried to count the number of ways I could form a 2 member or 3 member committee out of n+1 members but that didn't work either.  I could solve this problem algebraically by transforming the right-hand side to $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and then proving this by induction but the question requires me to give a combinatorial proof and I can't seem to figure out how...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Maybe try forming a team with three jobs (head, development, and accounting maybe?). The head has to be the oldest of the team, development and accounting can be done by the same person, but don't have to be.

hint: there are $m^2$ oder pairs you can choose from ${1,2,3,...,m}$, so the sum of squares is clear, now count ordered pairs using binomial to get the right side.

I think you'll find this post illuminating.


I included a poorly drawn picture to make myself a bit more clear. So we have $n$ squares, the first contains a single cell, the next then $2^2$ and so on till $n^2$ cells. If we add the cells in each square separately we get the number $1+2^2+3^2+\ldots+n^2$. If we change the way we count to adding the cells at each level we get:

$1+2+\ldots+n$ on the first level
$2+3+\ldots+n$ on the second level
$3+4+\ldots+n$ on the third level

and so on, I hope you get the idea. The number on the first level is exactly $1+2+\ldots+n=\binom{n+1}{2}$ and on the $i$-th level it is $\binom{n+1}{2}-\binom{i}{2}$. Adding this up gives
\begin{align}
\binom{n+1}{2}+\sum\limits_{i=2}^n(\binom{n+1}{2}-\binom{i}{2})&=\binom{n+1}{2}+(n-1)\binom{n+1}{2}-\sum\limits_{i=2}^n\binom{i}{2}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{2}+(n-1)\binom{n+1}{2}-\binom{n+1}{3}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{2}+3\binom{n+1}{3}-\binom{n+1}{3}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom{n+1}{3}.
\end{align}
Don't know whether it is what you were looking for tho, as it uses facts about binomial coefficients.
